# Weyl group is finite

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions

In theorem 6.36. in the book compact Lie groups by Sepanski, the argument used to prove that the Weyl group is finite is the following

> Since the set of roots $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}, \mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C})$ is finite and since the Weyl group $W$ acts faithfully on $\Delta(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}, \mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C})$, then $W$ is finite.

Why this is true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $W$ acts faithfully on a finite set, $W$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group on the set of roots. As a subgroup of a finite group, $W$ is finite.

Comment: why is W a subgroup of the symmetric group? Could you elaborate further please .

Comment: This is literally one of the definitions of faithful action. What is your definition of a faithful action?

Comment: The other common definition of a group $G$ acting faithfully on a set $X$ is that $gx = x$ for all $x \in X$ iff $g = id$. This means that the homomorphism from $G$ into $S_X$ is injective so $G$ "is"  a subgroup of $S_X$.

Comment: Dionel, I got it thanks a lot !